# Change Background position onClick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I would like to change the background position of one link when another link is clicked.  I want this to change:

```
<a class="fast btn-slide" href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an onclick event handler to the link and change/add a predefined class to the link

```
<style type="text/css">
.ThirdClassName { position:absolute;left:25px;top:25px; }
</style>
```

<a class="fast btn-slide" href="#" onclick="this.className += ' ThirdClassName'"></a>

This adds a class behind the others that are currently defined